# An event to be fired on editing a file

Tags: development, document-library, event-handlers, event-receivers, splistitem

As title says, I need an event to fire when a listitems file has been edited.

I appreciate this isn't as simple as it having it's own event, which is why I've tried to make use of the itemupdating event. Unfortunately, I can't find the relevant fields needed to monitor a change in the file belonging to the list item. I can monitor versions - and I'm pretty sure I have a good grip on how to monitor whether the event was fired because the document was being published or not - but this doesn't cater for simply just editing the file.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the SPItemEventReceiver BeforeProperties and AfterProperties.

You have 6 event receivers to choose from:

- ItemAdding
- ItemAdded
- ItemUpdating
- ItemUpdated
- ItemDeleting
- ItemDeleted

Look at this article here to explain it further.
http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: Thanks Mike, like I said in my OP though - I'm well into utilising these different event receivers, my question is how do I tell if the event was fired because the item's file was edited?